# Preference.setLayoutResource(R.layout.my_custom_layout) don't accept OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-settings

I am trying to set up a simple SettingsFragment with one of the Preference customized with an layout xml and set OnClickListener on this customised Preference. For this moment none of the way work.
What I miss please ?

I have tryed implements of OnPreferenceClickListener and OnPreferenceTreeClickListener but without succes.

This is my delete_btn_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/delete_account_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.package.SettingsActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_account_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_b"
        android:text="@string/delete_account"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/background_btn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_s" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my Preference element in <PreferenceScreen .../>

```
...
    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/account_category">

        <Preference
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_primary_dark_24"
            app:key="delete_account"
            app:title="@string/delete_account"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
...
```

And this is my SettingsFragment whit one "...ClickListener" witch don't work

```
    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

            Preference test = SettingsFragment.this.findPreference("delete_account");
            if (test != null) {
                test.setLayoutResource(R.layout.delete_btn_layout);
                test.setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
                    ViewWidgets.showSnackBar(1,getView(),"delete ?");
                    // do some action
                    return true;
                });
            } else {
                ViewWidgets.showSnackBar(1,getView(),"Error, Please retray.");
            }
        }
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may encounter a similar problem, I describe the solution that I applied.
The event detection of the click, I inserted in the activity (`class SettingsActivity`) that holds the SettingsFragment. With the "deleteUserAccount" method which initializes the process:

```
    public void deleteUserAccount(View view) {
        openDialog();
    }
```

The referance for this event I inserted in the button in the old way with the "onClick" method:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_account_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_b"
        android:text="@string/delete_account"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/background_google_btn"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_s"
        android:onClick="deleteUserAccount"/>
```